# Finding orthogonal projection of vector on space

Tags: linear-algebra

need to find  orthogonal projection of v on 2 diffrent w spaces
$$
  v=  \begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    4\\
6\\
    8\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

1.$$
  w= span \begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
    0\\
-1\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\ 
    -1\\
1\\
    -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

2.$$
  w= span \begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
    0\\
1\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\ 
    1\\
0\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\ 
   0\\
1\\
    -1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

the answers should be vector like v (4 rows) thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: idk what to do :( im sorry if it seems very basic, I have a few of t.hose questions with similar numbers like 0 0 1 -1 on last vector of w on q2.
at this case for example to book said the answer is 6 0 2  4

Comment: @GhnbTrcv There are a number of ways that a problem like this can be attacked, and some may not make sense to you depending on what you're learning currently. First, what book are you reading from? What kinds of topics have you been covering recently? Do words/phrases like "Gram-Schmidt", "Normal Equation", or even "Pseudoinverse" ring any bells? Let us know the context for this question, otherwise you might get an unhelpful answer, or more likely, have your question closed.

Comment: yes Gram-Schmid is the thing I think

Comment: @GhnbTrcv Okay! So, next question, could you perform Gram-Schmidt on either of these sets of vectors? That would be the first step.

Comment: yes because they are independent, for 1st one the set of orthonormal vector is 
\begin{bmatrix}
    sqrt2/(2)\\ 
    0\\
- sqrt2/(2)\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1/2\\ 
   -1/2\\
1/2\\
    -1/2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @GhnbTrcv Great! The first one was kinda easy, thankfully. Now, the way you project onto the span of an orthonormal (or even just orthogonal) basis is to sum the projections onto its basis vectors. So, if your orthogonal basis is $u_1, u_2$, and you wish to project $v$, the projection comes to:$$\frac{v \cdot u_1}{\|u_1\|^2}u_1 + \frac{v \cdot u_2}{\|u_2\|^2}u_2.$$In this case, since you've normalised, you can ignore the denominator of $\|u_1\|^2$ and $\|u_2\|^2$ as they are both $1$. Try using this formula. What do you get?

Comment: I think I got it wrong I got (1 0 3 0 ) + (0.5 1 1.5 -0.25)
but the answer is (-3 1 1 1)

Comment: According to my own calculations, their answer is correct. I'm not sure how to read your answer, as the first vector looks like it's in $\Bbb{R}^5$, while the second might be in $\Bbb{R}^3$. It might help to retreat back to the orthogonal version, without the square roots, and just divide by the square norms? I can't say something specific without seeing your working on the subject.

Comment: I just did the calculation (2 4 6 8)* (sqrt2/(2) 0 -sqrt2/(2) 0) * (sqrt2/(2) 0 -sqrt2/(2) 0) + (2 4 6 8 ) * (0.5 -0.5 0.5 -0.5) *(0.5 -0.5 0.5 -0.5)

Comment: can you show me what u did?

Comment: The first term is$$\frac{(2,4,6,8)\cdot(1,0,-1,0)}{\|(1,0,-1,0)\|^2}(1,0,-1,0)=\frac{2\cdot1+4\cdot0+6\cdot(-1)+8\cdot0}{1^2+0^2+(-1)^2+0}(1,0,-1,0)=\frac{-4}{2}(1,0,-1,0)=(-2,0,2,0).$$See if you can work out the other term. Then just add them up, and you should get $(-3,1,1,1)$. (Important reminder: we can only attack this question like this, because the basis is *orthogonal*.) P.S. You should put commas between your terms in your vectors to help make them more readable.